# Getting page location in ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

When I am using iframes or frames (older sites), as a extra security precaution I use the JavaScript function:

```
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.1">
  if (top == self) self.location.href = "../index.cfm";
 </SCRIPT>
```

then another hidden check to see if the page is being called correctly....

```
 <cfif (HTTP_REFERER DOES NOT CONTAIN "referer_page.cfm")
  <cfabort> 
 </cfif>
```

It works great to keep visitors (hackers?) from opening and/or trying to post to the page.

The problem is that the JavaScript displays in source code and the less they know...

I know the JS is client side but is there anyway to create the function in the server side CF or otherwise hide from prying eyes?

I a running cf9 on my and most of my client sites.

Thank in advance

Comment: Is the checking for the HTTP_REFERER safe? I mean, i've seen in the past that because of browser or security settings it can be blank.

Comment: FYI: the `language` attribute on the `<script>` tag has been deprecated since I think 1999.  You did say 'older sites'!

Comment: FYI, ColdFusion 9 reaches end of core support at the end of 2014. You should start upgrading the sites to CF 11 (or Railo) asap. https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/eol/eol_matrix.html#63

Comment: This tag still works fine in IE, Safari, Firefox and Chrome. All but IE latest versions.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible for any server side language to tell if the client that requested a page intends on displaying it inside of a frame.  The only way to tell that is to ask the browser once your page reaches it.

What's the concern with the Javascript being visible?

Comment: Hi Brad, Just trying to put another unseen block in their way. I am not so much concerned with them opening a page somewhere else though I don't appreciate it as I am a hacker trying to pass a function through the URL. The CF does not appear in source code so just something else to make it less worth their time to hack.

Comment: Use a JavaScript obfuscator then.  It won't stop anyone who's determined, but it might make it a bit more annoying.

Answer (score 2):

There is literally *nothing* you can do to permanently avoid  clients from seeing your source HTML and/or Javascript. Any attempt at security on the client side is in the end futile. You will keep out casual (i.e. non-web developer or programmer) users, but that is all. Anyone with a rudimentary knowledge of HTML and access to Google (or Alta Vista or ask jeeves for that matter) will be able to circumvent your barriers.

The use of HTTP_REFERER is suspect here as well (I know I know... I'm a negative Nellie :). That CGI var is dependent on the browser and web server working together. It will not be reliable overall because it is dependent on the client side. Someone up to no good will have no problem circumventing your barrier by simply constructing requests with the appropriate referrer.

If you want server side security then you are forced to use some form of authentication and session. This is a growing field what with oAuth and the use of Google, FB, Twitter etc as federated authenticaiton services. But plain old usernames and passwords tied to login sessions works too :)

Comment: Hi Mark, Seeing my html & HavaScript source is not what I am concerned with. I know there is no way to stop that. I put a few little stumbling blocks in CF that make it that much harder to write to a CF page via the URL. I would like to hide the Location in CF so they can't see that either is all. You know it's evil out there so we got to always be thinking.

Comment: this JS tag might be old but it seems to work fine on IE, Safari, Chrome and Firefox. I can see where a path could be constructed with the referrer calling the page which is why I have some CF also checking for a variable or 2. All you can do with a really determined hacker is to make it not worth his time to try to crack your defenses but even NSA has been cracked.

Comment: Andy, I'm not sure what you mean by "Write to a CF page via the URL". Do you mean POST to a cf page, pass url variables? You mean obscure the actual CFM file name? I would suggest stringent error trapping and URL reWriting as a solution in that case.

Comment: @MarkAKruger That may be my fault. I might have confused him. I was explaining how via inspect element, you can alter a live document. He took that to mean that it was a method of altering the server-side file via the browser. I was merely trying to highlight a(nother) reason why server side enforcement is the better solution. Security-wise, Javascript is about as potent as the gates that come down at railroad tracks.

Comment: Hi Mark, That is what this post was all about in the first place. I just want to do the same i.e divert anyone trying to open, post to or in any way have access to any page except the default index.cfm where I have lots of cf code to - server side - pick out and (hopefully) block the attacks. Just want to keep as much hidden as possible.

Comment: I would definitely look at URL Rewrite and combine it with OnRequestStart to filter out any direct cfm file access (if you see what I mean).

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, @Luke is saying that some users properly using your site, viewing iframe content, may have problems if they have a security setting, like an anonymity program, blocking their data, like cgi variables.

The only real solution is proper authentication and filtering on every page. If a list shows content for a user and loads details into an iframe, the iframe's page must also check that the user has access. At that point, it doesn't matter if they can get at the url.

For instance, if you get a list of user images like this.

```
<cfquery name="getImageList">
  select imageid,imagefilename_mini
    from images
   where userid = <cfqueryparam value="#session.userid#">
</cfquery>
```

Which loads an iframe to load full sized images, you still need the and subclause

```
<cfquery name="getThisImage">
  select imagefilename from images
   where imageID = ...
     and userID = ...
</cfquery>
```

That way, even if someone changes the image id in the url, it still only lets them see content bound to the userID.

Also, modern browsers make altering the source of a live page all too easy. I don't mean that browsers can alter the server side file, I mean that contents of the DOM as delivered to the browser. It's an incredibly useful tool for developing and debugging, but it does make mischievous/malevolent activity easier.

In chrome and firefox, you can inspect an element, change the attributes and the page will change before your eyes. Here, that works for iframe src's, so it still is within the DOM it expects to be in.

You should regard client side UI as how you'd like the page to be presented, and the way it works best but use server side safeguarding (proper validation) because it's too easy to get around client-controlled data/elements.

Comment: Hi CFQP... Just trying to make a data insertion attack as hard a possible (what they don't know) as possible. That the JS displays in source is what concerns me. If there is a CF solution they would not see it and thus wouldn't know exactly why the are stopped. note that my second tag which causes an abort so all they see is a blank page.

Comment: I don't understand how anyone could actually save an altered page to my server. If that were possible there would not be a secure page anywhere I would think. Plus server side generated pages are just that and they do not even exist until the server outputs them.

Comment: @Andy You cannot hide javascript. You can use obfusicators to to make it harder to read, but there are tools to de-fusicate.

Also when I say "modern browsers" make altering a live page all too easy. I that you can alter the presentation of the page, alter IFRAME sources, as they're displayed to you. It doesn't make a permanent change to the page. However, if the iframe has a source of imageviewer.cfm?id=1, I can use Inspect Element to change that to id=2 and chrome will display the change immediately. But no. View Source / Inspect Element makes no changes to the web server.

Comment: Yes CFQP.... That is why I posted this question in the first place. Move the function to the server side where the reason a hacker is being diverted is not readily apparent. Just trying to frustrate them so they go find some other site to play with.